# How can I delete all blocked users with Drush?

Tags: drupal, drush

How can I delete all blocked users with Drush?  I have hundreds of blocked users from spammers.  I want to delete all these users.  I tried doing it through the web interface, but this only works for about 20 users at a time.  I have 60 pages to delete, which takes too long and is unsustainable.  Also, I want all the relevant callbacks to be run when a blocked user is deleted, and I want all its content deleted.  I noticed `user-cancel`, but this appears to only apply to a single user.  Is there a way to make this command work with all blocked users?

Comment: Here is your response :). Custom module for drupal 7. In the admin/people area there is a new form for complete this operation. Too with drush. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/how-to-delete-blocked-users-in-bulk/85300#85300

Answer (score 4):

Using Drupal 7 and Drush 5.9, the way I did was:

1- Create an alias "@example-local" to your local Drupal installation, as shown [here](https://drupal.org/node/1401522).

2- Create a script file called "delete-blocked-users.script", at, say, "/Users/username/scripts/drush", with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush

$users = db_query("SELECT * FROM {users} WHERE (status = 0)");
foreach ($users as $user) {
  exec("drush @example-local user-cancel $user->name -y");
}
```

3- Make the script file executable with:

```
chmod +x ~/scripts/drush/delete-blocked-users.script
```

4- And finally, run the script using:

```
drush @example-local scr ~/scripts/drush/delete-blocked-users.script
```

This will delete all the blocked users (users with status = 0), without asking for confirmation (defined by the -y flag).

Answer (score 2):

Drush does not have a simple command to delete all blocked accounts. It would probably be easier to set up a [vbo](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) view in you admin interface that lets you filter for blocked users then you can select all and cancel.

You can also run a php script with `drush php-script script.php`.

So you can set up a php script that does a query for blocked users then loops through though users and calls the user cancel function.

Answer (score -2):

Besides drush, is just easier access to mysql data using user, password and database name that you can find in file drupalhomedir/sites/default/setting.php with command:

```
mysql -u username-at-setting -ppassword-at-setting database-at-setting
```

then delete all records on drupal 'user' table with:

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE status=0;
```

Comment: While technically correct, this will delete records from the users table but would orphan a lot of data that is attached to a user in Drupal.  Custom fields and contributed content would all be left behind.